# Pycharm dependencies are missing in Editor - Installed requirements.txt in a specified folder

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I'm working in a PyCharm Project for Google App Engine. According to the Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#pip_requirements) I have to use the following code to install the requirements:

```
pip install -t dependencies  -r requirements.txt
```

This creates an folder 'dependencies' with all the packages in it.

Pycharm don't recognize this folder so all installed packages (e. g. Flask) are underlined red --> autocomplete and functions like that don't work.

[image]

Is there a setting in PyCharm for setting the dependency folder?

PS: The code works fine, if I run the project it works locally and on the Google App Engine.

Here is a screenshot from my project interpreter and pip freeze:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you set up your python interpreter 'in pycharm' correctly? Can run your code from the pycharm's inbuilt terminal?

Comment: Isn't that because Flask is only supported in the professional edition of Pycharm that it does not recognize the names and does not auto-complete? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/flask.html

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy yes I can run the code from the unbuild terminal.

Comment: @Eskapp I'm using the professional version of Pycharm.

Comment: post a screen shot of your interpreter configuration? and a  pip freeze from inbuilt terminal

Comment: Try to mark `dependencies` folder as `Sources Root` through `Right-click - Mark Directory As`

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy added the screenshots to the question

Comment: @user2235698 didn't work to mark the folder as Sources Root